# $b\in A\subset \mathbb R^n$, $f(b)=0$, $f(x_1,x_2,...,b_i, x_{i+1},...,x_n)=0$ for any $b_ix\in A$. Then $f(y)=0$ for any $y\in A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I was reading a book saying that the proof is simple and thus omitted. However I am not able to find a simple proof.

**Problem:**

Fixed vector $b\in A\subset \mathbb R^n, n\ge 3$,

$A$ is a connected hypersurface.

Known: $f(b)=0$.

Variable $\alpha,x,y\in\mathbb R^n$

Define $\alpha_ix=(x_1,x_2,...,x_{i-1},\alpha_i,x_{i+1},...,x_n)$ *(Comment: Please let me know the standard notation for these kind of vectors)*

Given that: if $f(\alpha)=0$, and $\alpha_ix\in A$, then $f(\alpha_ix)=0$

**Prove that** $f(y)=0$ for any $y\in A$.

---

**My try:**

First observe that $f(b_1x)=0$ for any $b_1x\in A$.

Then, we need to prove that , for any $x$, $f(y_1x)=0$ for any $y$ such that $y_1x\in A$.

Fix any $x$,

Let $y_i=x_i$ for any $i>1$.

Since, $f(b_1x)=0$,

Then $f(x_2y)=0$ whenever $x_2y\in A$

Since $x_2y=y_1x$, we have $f(y_1x)=0$ for any $y$ such that $y_1x\in A$.

QED

*Can the proof be improved?*

Comment: Suppose that $n=2$,  $A$ consists of two points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. Suppose that $f(0,0)=0$. How do you show that $f(1,1)=0$?

Comment: @markvs A is a connected hypersurface - updated

Comment: And where in your proof do you use that $A$ is a connected hypersurface?

Comment: @markvs It should be used. I am figuring it out right now. So the proof could be wrong in the current state.

Comment: The proof is certainly wrong.

Comment: @markvs Trying now

Comment: Good luck!${}{}{}{}$